# LD_PRELOAD help

Tags: c++, unix, shared-libraries, ld

I'm trying to use LD_PRELOAD.

**original.cpp**

```
void myPuts() {  
    puts ("Hello myPuts");  
}  
int main() {  
    myPuts();  
    return 0;  
}
```

**hacked.cpp**

```
void myPuts() {  
    std::cout >> "Hello hacked myPuts";  
}
```

I compile original.cpp:

```
g++ original.cpp
```

And hacked.cpp:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC hacked.cpp
```

I try:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./hacked.so ./original.out
```

The string "Hello hacked myPuts" should be seen, by "Hello myPuts" appears.
(If I try to "overwrite" the puts function, it works correctly)

What am I missing?

Comment: If you're posting a block of code, you can indent each line with a minimum of 4 spaces and the site will automatically format it as code. The advantage of this method over the backticks is that you get syntax highlighting. You can also highlight the entire block and click the `{}` button on the toolbar. Just so you know for future reference. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have:

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {  
    myPuts();  
    return 0;  
}
```

**original.cpp**

```
void myPuts() {  
    puts ("Hello myPuts");  
}
```

**hacked.cpp**

```
void myPuts() {  
    std::cout << "Hello hacked myPuts";  
}
```

Compiling all:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC original.cpp -o liboriginal.so
g++ -shared -fPIC hacked.cpp -o libhacked.so
g++ main.cpp -loriginal -o main.out
```

And using:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libhacked.so ./main.out
```

Comment: Wonderfull, thank you! Last question: **g++ main.cpp -loriginal** doesnt't work for me; I'm getting a **cannot find -loriginal** error message :-(

Comment: You should compile original.cpp with `g++ -shared -fPIC original.cpp -o liboriginal.so`. With the correct naming in libXXX.so, the linker will find the lib when compiling main.cpp.

Comment: For future reference: compiling main.cpp with -L ./ tells the compiler, to look for libraries in the current directory. Running main.out: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./ ./main.out (this way liboriginal.so will be searched in the current directory)

Answer (score 6):

From man ld.so

> LD_PRELOAD
>
> A whitespace-separated list of additional, user-specified, ELF shared libraries to be loaded before all others. This can  be  used  to selectively override functions in **other shared libraries**.

If myPuts was in shared library linked to main application it would work, but not when
myPuts exists in the application and does not resolved in an external library.

Comment: Note that if the application is built in such a way that the function in question remains a weak symbol after final link, it may be possible to override its functions from the shared library - but this requires cooperation from the application's developer.